# Cross-Browser Display Problems (Safari, Chrome, Firefox, iEx)

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, safari

The h1 across different browsers is not rendering in a universal fashion, and I think I'm going bald because of it.![enter image description here][1] It looks as if the weight is a little thicker and I'm curious as to how to fix the issue.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xYdN.jpg

```
    element {
}
.carousel--home .item h1 {
    font-size: 70px;
    font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #5E5E5F;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    line-height: 1;
}
h1, .h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
}
h1, .h1, h2, .h2, h3, .h3 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, .h1, .h2, .h3, .h4, .h5, .h6 {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.1;
    color: inherit;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0.67em 0px;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.carousel--home .item .item__text {
    text-align: center;
}
body {
    color: #5E5E5F;
    font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.42;
}
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    color: #333;
}
html {
    font-size: 10px;
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your CSS?

Comment: Is it normal to render it so differently?

Comment: Have you loaded the roboto font?  My guess is you are getting slightly different fonts in different browsers because it's using sans serif.

Comment: Can you post the CSS for the `<h1>` element in question?

Comment: Yes the font is loaded.

Comment: check and compare your default font settings in each browser... set the default in each to Sans Serif (16pt).. - IE English default...
In Internet Options>General tab, Accessibility button, make sure
"Ignore font styles specified on web pages" and "Ignore font sizes specified on web pages" are unchecked... IE, Opera and FX also accept userStylesheets.
In each browsers Developer tool use the DOM Explorer find tool to select and explore the applied styles... webkit also shows the default userAgent style rules.